# Get current user data

Tags: filters, users

I do work on filter posts by current user, but in my dropdown list, i can get only all users list, but I need to see only the current user

```
function getСurrentUserForFilter(){
    $res = '';
    $user_query = new WP_User_Query(array('number'=>999));
    $users = $user_query->get_results();
    foreach($users as $user){
        echo'<option value="'.$user->ID.'">'.$user->user_email.'</option>';
    }
    return $res;
}
```

what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to write a single `<option>` for the current user, you can get the user object from [wp_get_current_user()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_current_user/) - you don't need a WP_User_Query at all:

```
function getСurrentUserForFilter() {
    if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
        $user = wp_get_current_user();
        echo '<option value="'.$user->ID.'">'.esc_html($user->user_email).'</option>';
    }
}
```